# Convert dot to dotx in JAVA

Tags: java, apache-poi, xwpf, hwpf

I have a `.dot` file using which i will be creating doc file with values replaced.

eg: `.dot` file having `<claimId>`

I will replace `<claimId>` with real claim Id say `1234` and generate a doc file.
I am using [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/document/index.html) `HWPFDocument`, when using `HWPFDocument` i am getting issues when i replace text inside table.

So i tried `XWPFDocument` i can feed only `.dotx` files.

I have no issue when using dotx file with `XWPFDocument` and successfully generated docx files. Now i need to convert .dot files to `.dotx` files from java.
Can someone help me on this...

Answer (score 1):

There is no automated way to do this conversion in Apache POI as far as I know.

You can manually convert .dot files to .dotx by opening the file in Microsoft Word and saving it in the newer format.

Comment: My problem is, client may not have the latest MS Office to update the documents to .dotx formats